# How to delete cell with parse data in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

hi I'm using `parse` to store my data for my application and want to be able to delete it when I swipe the cell left, though when I click delete I have to manually pull down and refresh in order for the data to go away.

Is there anyway of making it animate and go away as soon as i click delete after swiping the cell?

This is the code i use to delete the cell data in my `ViewController.m`:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    // Remove the row from data model
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        [self refreshControl];
        [tableView reloadData];



    }];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were calling the method before you even knew if the data was successfully deleted.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) { 
    //try this
    PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //found the code for removing a row. 
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    // Remove the row from data model
    [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
      if (!succeeded){
        //we had an error
        // gives the error log and also how it relates to the user. 
        NSLog(ERROR: %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }
    }];
  }
}
```

EDIT: Try out the edited solution above.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I added this code and I still have to manually refresh, am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To make the cell properly animate, you need to achieve these things:

1. Update the backend server (Parse) model = delete the cell data
2. Update the client model (in this case `self.objects`)
3. Animate the cell correspondingly

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
    forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // 2. Update client model
        [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // 3. Animate cells
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        // 1. Update backend model
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // If the backend reports an error, you'd need to readd the cell or
                // display an error message to the user
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error for [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: if I get rid of [self.objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; then build and run, when I click the delete button the app crashes...any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'

Comment: Thats the problem. Objects is an NSArray, removeObjectAtIndex is an NSMutableArray method.

Comment: What do I replace it with?

Comment: Where is objects declared? it should be NSMutableArray in everyplace where there is NSArray. If its a property than its ``@property NSMutableArray *objects;`` Immutable objects (like NSArray) cannot be modified (adding, removing objects) once the object has been created. This is true for all classes that have mutable counterparts such as NSData (NSMutableData), NSDictionary (NSMutableDictionary), NSSet (NSMutableSet), and all other data-structure classes.

Comment: my variables in the database are all NSString

Comment: can a NSString be an NSArray?

Comment: an NSString and an NSArray are two different objects. An NSArray can have string elements, and you can cast elements to an NSString form an array.

Comment: i can't find anything with NSArray or NSMutableArray in my project except in the code provided

Comment: would you like me to email you my project so you can see my setup?

Comment: Do you have a github with the project on it?

Comment: no, not at the moment though I could make an account and put it on github...or would email be easier?

Comment: `self.objects = [[[[self.objects] mutableCopy] removeObjectAtIndex:x] copy];`

Comment: upload it to gitHub. I recommend learning gitHub since it will allow you to backup your projects.

Comment: sorry, it should be there now